# How to start a fish instance with a specific `config.fish`?

Tags: fish

I want to start a particular `fish` instance with a specific `config.fish`.

Something along the lines of the Bash `--rcfile` option.

I'm aware of the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` variable. But I just want to switch the config for fish. Not for other programs using XDG I would run *from* that fish instance.

Comment: here's a hack: temporarily swap out the config file: `cd ~/.config/fish; mv config.fish config.fish~; ln my.other.config.fish config.fish; fish &; mv config.fish~ config.fish; fg`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the [`--init-command=COMMANDS` startup option was added in fish 2.7](https://fishshell.com/docs/2.7/commands.html#fish)

Something along the line of that *should* do the trick:

```
 fish --init-command='source /path/to/alternate/fish.config'
```

But I'm unable to test since we are using here fish 2.4.0. Maybe is there a workaround?

Comment: Note that `--init-command` does not suppress reading the default config file.